# How to replace the blank

Tags: regex, string, replace, ironpython

Given the code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System')

from System.Text.RegularExpressions import *

def ReplaceBlank(st):
    return Regex.Replace(
        st,r'[^a-z\s](\s+)[^a-z\s]',
        lambda s:s.Value.Replace(' ', ''),RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I expect the input `ABC EDF` to return `ABCDEF` but it doesn't work, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry Konrad Rudolph, I think we edited at the same time hehe **rollback**

Comment: @Koning: Stack Overflow should probably distribute locks for concurrent edits to prevent lost updates … oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^a-z\s]` with ignore-case flag set matches anything other than letters and whitespace characters. `^` at the beginning of a character class (the thing between `[]`) negates the character class.

To replace blanks, you can simply replace `\s+` with empty strings or, if you need to match only letters replace

```
(?<=[a-z])\s+(?=[a-z])
```

with an empty sting. The second regex will match string of whitespaces between two letters; to account for beginning/end of strings, use

```
(?<=(^|[a-z]))\s+(?=($|[a-z]))
```

or

```
\b\s+\b
```

The second one will match spaces between two word boundaries, which include symbol chars like period, comma, hyphen etc.